# Oracle database, converting unique index to non-unique one

Tags: oracle

I understand I can't do this straightforward from studying similar questions on stackoverflow and other sites.

However, I need to do this and I'm willing to go with workarounds.

I tried to create a non-unique index with `online` and `parallel`, and then drop the old unique index. However, it fails saying `ORA-01408: such column list already indexed`.

How to convert an unique index to a non-unique one?

Comment: You'll have to drop the old index then create the new one.

Comment: @BobJarvis How will this impact select performance in between?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to drop the old index before creating the new one, you can cheat a bit by creating the new index with an additional useless column, e.g.:

Assuming a table with the following configuration:

```
create table mytable (id number);

create unique index myunique on mytable (id);
```

To convert the index to non unique:

```
create index temp on mytable (id, 1);

drop index myunique;

create index mynonunique on mytable (id);

drop index temp;
```

In practice I'm not sure how necessary this is - generally I'd just drop and recreate the index in some low-activity period, preferably take the application down.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle now supports multiple indexes applied to the same set of columns as long as they differ in uniqueness (and/or in some other properties such as bitmap vs. btree and partitioning) and
as long as only one of them is visible.

Therefore you can alter the existing index - changing it to invisible without dropping it and then create a new non-unique index.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id NUMBER);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_unique_idx ON mytable(id);

ALTER INDEX mytable_unique_idx INVISIBLE;

CREATE INDEX mytable_nonunique_idx ON mytable(id);
```

Note that invisible indexes are still maintained by the database and you can change between them by turning one of them to invisible and the second one to visible.